# É interessante criar um tipo só para um ponteiro para um tipo?

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro, tipagem

Já vi fazendo um

```
MinhaEstrutura *
```

ser explicitamente tipificado como

```
typedef MinhaEstrutura * pMinhaEstrutura;
```

Por que não fazer sempre assim e se livra de ficar tendo que dereferenciar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É tudo uma questão de semântica. Qual é a intenção do seu código? Ele deve saber que há um ponteiro ali? Então deixe o ponteiro exposto e não crie um tipo para deixar o ponteiro opaco. Criar um tipo assim indica que você não deve mexer com ponteiro.

Se a intenção é não mostrar que tem um ponteiro ali, por que usar o prefixo `p` no tipo que é a notação húngara para ponteiro? O maior erro está aí. A não ser que a intenção era mostrar que é um ponteiro, aí o `typedef` não deve ser uado.

Na verdade isso não desobrigará "derreferenciar", então ele não é tão opaco assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { int x; } MinhaEstrutura;

typedef MinhaEstrutura * MeuTipo;

int main(void) {
    MinhaEstrutura dado = { 1 };
    MeuTipo var = &dado; //teve que usar o operador para pegar o endereço
    printf("%d", var->x); //teve que usar -> para acessar o membro
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xhwCnW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cpfvvgsh-maniero).  Também [coloquei no **Github** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/OpaquePointer.c).

É possível para o compilador tratar o ponteiro de forma transparente, mas em C e C++ isto não é feito, então raramente é vantagem tentar a opacidade. Se conforme com a linguagem onde ponteiros estão por toda parte ou mude de linguagem.

Em C++ é mais fácil deixar opaco. O que algumas pessoas fazem é deixar o ponteiro dentro de um tipo e seu acesso ser feito através de operadores sobrecarregados, mas não é um simples `typedef` que irá resolver.